# What is Pygame font.SysFont() font-size measurement unit? How do I certain if the rendered text is 1 cm for the X char in height?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have spent hours looking for the used measurement unit of the `pygame.font.SysFont()`'s font size. I didn't find any site that tells me the measurement unit. What I want to achieve is how to render with exactly 1 cm in height, if we measure the uppercase X at the monitor.

I have seen pygame freetype, but I'm not sure what is that and how to use that. The docs didn't explain it very well, so I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're searching for ? :
"Load a new font from a given filename or a python file object. The size is the height of the font in pixels. If the filename is None the pygame default font will be loaded. If a font cannot be loaded from the arguments given an exception will be raised. Once the font is created the size cannot be changed."

Check the URL : https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html
There are many references to size, plus a pygame function about size... Can be interesting

Comment: Ouch I think I missed that part. I'll try some experiments right now. Can I ask you again if I encounter any problem about the size? hehe

Comment: Hey I just had to search "pygame.font.SysFont() font size" on google and I clicked on the FIRST link XD

Comment: My dpi is 144. I set the SysFont("monospace", 283) and render the uppercase X. Please note that 283 px is about 1.965 inches and about 5 cm at my current DPI. When I measure it with my ruler in the monitor, the surface height is 5 cm, but the X itself just 3 cm. Is it possible to get the X exactly 5 cm in height? Thank you for the further help ^^ :D

Comment: Can't you just define a mathematic relation between 1 pixel and 1 cm or 1 inch ?
And so you just got to multiply or divide by this number and it's much simpler !